# Clear all bootstrap-ui modals using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When a session times out, we need to clear any open modals. What is the best technique for this? I'm trying to stay away from jQuery and keep it pure Angular.

Our modals are opened in the following way:

```
//configure the modal
      var modalOptions = {
        controller: 'modalCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        windowClass: 'modal-class',
        transclude: true
      };

      // open the modal
      myModal = $modal.open(modalOptions);
```

I've tried simulating clicks on the backdrop and simulating the escape key with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is very easy: it is enough to inject the `$modalStack` service and call the `dismissAll` method on it:

```
$modalStack.dismissAll(reason);
```

ex.:

```
$modalStack.dismissAll('session timeout');
```